# Why doesn't User.Identity.IsAuthenticated work on a page loaded using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Why doesn't `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` work on page that has been loaded using ajax?

In my view have this code:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  ...
}
else
{
  ...
}
```

but when this View/Controller is loaded using ajax `@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` is always *false* and goes to the else section.

I don't know why this happens.

Is it possible that this problem is due to the loading with ajax?

Comment: Have you checked that `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `true` when making a standard page request?

Comment: Yes , return true in main-page/standard-page

Comment: Show us how you do your AJAX request and where you check for authentication?

Comment: Have you already setting both `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` in AJAX action method and forms authentication in web.config? Ensure the method makes next request after `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` method has executed (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto when i login in my site its ok and return to Default url when set on webconfig. BUT when go to root site and manually go to default url , i must login again ! And this will be repeated Over and Over

Comment: @trailmax i load ajax with this `$("#LoadPages").load(e);`. e is address page and in view   i check this `@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` . in standard page work perfect but in ajax load does not work !

Comment: AJAX callback intended to return certain element(s) on same page and not for entire page unlike standard POST does, hence you need to make at least one redirect after using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", true);` before `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` state becomes `true`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Can you explain more?